# SDL_BlitSurface() having no effect

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm developing a game, and I can't seem to draw to the screen at all.  When I call  SDL_BlitSurface, nothing happens.  However, it does not return an error code.  I've written a class to handle image sprites, and when I step through with a debugger, I see it is returning non-empty values for the surface to blit to the main video surface.  When I call my draw function, however, it does nothing.  I have confirmed that the pixel values are not changed at all for the surface.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my main.cpp:

```
//Standard libs
#include <SDL.h>

//Our gaming base
#include "game_base.h"

//SDL redefines main as winmain, but this is a console application so we don't want that
#undef main

const int MAX_FPS = 80;

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    //Initialization
    System game( false, 640, 480, "Platformer", MAX_FPS ); //Create a game that is not fullscreen with a resolution of 640x480
    SDL_Surface *buffer = NULL;
    Input *input = NULL;
    buffer = game.get_buffer();
    Image_Sprite *player_sprite = NULL;
    player_sprite = new Image_Sprite( "data/player.bmp", 1, 4 );
    SDL_Rect hitbox;
    hitbox.w = 32;
    hitbox.h = 32;
    hitbox.x = 0;
    hitbox.y = 0;
    Player player( 100, 100, hitbox, 1.0, RIGHT, player_sprite );
    //Main game loop
    while( !game.check_is_done() ) {
        game.refresh_top();
        player.draw( buffer );
        game.refresh_bottom();
    }

    //Cleanup
    delete input;
    delete player_sprite;
}
```

And this is the draw function I'm using:

```
void Character::draw( SDL_Surface *destination ) {
    SDL_Rect coordinates;
    SDL_Surface *sprite;
    sprite = my_sprite->get_frame( my_frame, my_direction );
    coordinates.x = (int)get_x();
    coordinates.y = (int)get_y();

    SDL_BlitSurface( sprite, NULL, destination, NULL );
}
```

Finally, here is ny get_frame() function:

```
SDL_Surface* Image_Sprite::get_frame( int x, int y ) {
    SDL_PixelFormat *format;
    format = my_sprite->format;
    SDL_Surface *frame = SDL_CreateRGBSurface( my_sprite->flags, my_frame_width, my_frame_height, format->BitsPerPixel,
                                                    format->Rmask, format->Gmask, format->Bmask, format->Amask );
    SDL_Rect *frame_crop = new SDL_Rect;
    frame_crop->x = my_frame_width * x;
    frame_crop->y = my_frame_height * y;
    frame_crop->w = my_frame_width;
    frame_crop->h = my_frame_height;

    SDL_Rect *coordinates = new SDL_Rect;
    coordinates->x = 0;
    coordinates->y = 0;

    SDL_BlitSurface( my_sprite, frame_crop, frame, coordinates );
    delete frame_crop;
    return frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SDL_Flip()` function per-frame to make the changes to the video surface visible. The argument to the function is a pointer to your window's SDL_Surface.

Comment: SDL_Flip( buffer ) is a part of System::refresh_bottom(). I'm sorry If I didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.  I was forgetting to initialize my_direction, so the sprite was cropping a nonsense location.  I ended up with a 32x32 black image, which I then blitted onto a black surface, rendering it invisible.